# Underset in author line

Tags: titles, authblk

I'm trying to modify the author line such that my name has a qualification below as the main applicant. I tried to do this using the `underset` like this:

```
$\underset{\footnotesize{\mbox{main applicant}}}{\mbox{Alejandro M. Aragón}}$
```

but it doesn't work as it gives me the following error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd
File: uwasy.fd 2003/10/30 v2.0 Wasy-2 symbol font definitions
)
./proposal.tex:97: Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.97 \vspace
            {-10ex}
?
```

I'm also using the `authblk` package in case this has something to do with it.

This is what I start with, it works but I would like to have the "main applicant" and "promotor" texts as undersets instead of in parenthesis.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{marvosym} % letter symbol
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-7em}

\title{This is the title}

\author[1]{Author One (main applicant)  \thanks{  \Letter:author1@email}}
\author[1]{Author Two (promotor) \thanks{  \Letter:author2@email}}
\affil[1]{\small{Affiliation, \break Address}}

\date{}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\vspace{-10ex}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `stackengine` package is versatile in this regard.  EDITED to use so-called long stacks, to avoid any stacking variances in the presence of letter descenders.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{marvosym} % letter symbol
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-7em}
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{.8\baselineskip}

\title{This is the title}

\author[1]{\stackunder{Author One}{\footnotesize (main applicant)}%
    \thanks{  \Letter:author1@email}}
\author[1]{\stackunder{Author Two}{\footnotesize (promotor)}%
   \thanks{  \Letter:author2@email}}
\affil[1]{\small{Affiliation, \break Address}}

\date{}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\vspace{-10ex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, it almost works except for the fact that the names have different baselines (one name has a `g` character). So the text (main applicant) and (promotor) are not aligned properly in the vertical direction.

Comment: I also tried to use `\phantom` to add a ghost character and align both but this doesn't work.

Comment: @aaragon You can either invoke `\def\stacktype{L}` in the preamble, which will force the stacks to use a baseline-to-baseline measurement, rather than a gap measurement, or else you could add `\strut` to the data entries.  Additionally the stacking gap can be set with `\setstackgap{L}{length}` for long or `{S}` for short stacks.

Comment: I had solved the issue by putting `{\color{white}g}` but of course this solution is not very elegant. Thanks again.

Comment: @aaragon I have edited my answer to reflect the more versatile approach.